# What is the optimal repetition pattern to maximize long term memory?

Tags: memory, learning, long-term-memory

Which is the appropriate repetition pattern to aid long term memory, in terms of time between study sessions?

I have been reading about Ebbinghaus and doing some related research, but I can't find a recent study on the effectiveness it may have if a certain pattern is used for distribuiting the learning sessions on a subject.

Comment: Also relevant to the question and Jeromy's answer is [my answer here](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/480/are-spaced-flashcards-effective-for-learning/481#481) the Forgetting Function is definitely something you'll want to look into

Answer (score 8):

It sounds like you are interested in the [Spacing Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacing_effect). 
A search on [Google Scholar for "spacing effect" for articles published since the year 2000](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22spacing+effect%22&btnG=Search&as_sdt=0%2C5&as_ylo=2000&as_vis=0) yields over 2500 articles some of which might be worth pursuing.

Perhaps you might want to start by having a read through the meta-analysis in *Psychological Bulletin* by Cepeda et al (2006). To quote the abstract:

> The authors performed a meta-analysis of the distributed practice
>   effect to illuminate the effects of temporal variables that have been
>   neglected in previous reviews. This review found 839 assessments of
>   distributed practice in 317 experiments located in 184 articles.
>   Effects of spacing (consecutive massed presentations vs. spaced
>   learning episodes) and lag (less spaced vs. more spaced learning
>   episodes) were examined, as were expanding interstudy interval (ISI)
>   effects. Analyses suggest that ISI and retention interval operate
>   jointly to affect final-test retention; specifically, the ISI
>   producing maximal retention increased as retention interval increased.

You may also want to read Pavlik and Anderson (2008). They used a computational model of known spacing and practice effects in order to try to develop an optimal practice schedule for maximising learning and retention.

#### References

- Cepeda, N.J. and Pashler, H. and Vul, E. and Wixted, J.T. and Rohrer, D. (2006). Distributed practice in verbal recall tasks: A review and quantitative synthesis. *Psychological bulletin, 132*, 354. [PDF](http://uweb.rc.usf.edu/~drohrer/pdfs/Cepeda_et_al_2006PsychBull.pdf)
- Pavlik, P. I and Anderson, J. R. (2008). Using a model to compute the optimal schedule of practice. *Journal of Experimental Psychology: Applied, 14*, 101. [PDF](http://server-1.optim.cs.cmu.edu/people/Articles/2008%20Pavlik%20Anderson.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The search terms "gradual-interval recall" may give you another area to research.  I found that in a blog posting about SRS

https://medium.com/p/5481606b087a

> "In a paper on gradual-interval recall published by Paul Pimsleur in
>   1967, he hypothesizes the following intervals: 5 seconds, 25 seconds,
>   2 minutes, 10 minutes, 1 hour, 5 hours, 1 day, 5 days, 25 days, 4
>   months, and 2 years. Although the exact intervals varied by subject,
>   Pimsleur’s intervals give you an idea about the exponential nature of
>   memory retention."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimsleur_method

Comment: "[The goal of this spaced recall is to help the student move vocabulary into long-term memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimsleur_method#Methodology)." Good stuff. Now if only we could replace studying with testing...Welcome to CogSci!

Comment: Is it feasible?