# Compared efficiency of different spaced-repetition memorisation techniques

Tags: memory, encoding, mnemonic

[Spaced repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) is a memorization technique that works by reviewing question/answer pairs according to a schedule that depends on performance.

Be it software or paper flashcards, there are various techniques to calculate the review schedule. For instance: Leitner, SM0, SM2, ... new techniques appear from time to time. 
Each new scheduling technique is trying to surpass the others, the goal being to calculate the intervals smartly, for instance so that a question is shown just before the student forgets the fact.

**Is there work comparing the "efficiency" of some of those scheduling techniques?** (few reviews, well-memorized) Preferably research involving a reasonable number of human experiments.

Comment: Here is a [related question](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/480/29) that might be of interest.

Comment: You may find the papers & fulltexts in http://www.gwern.net/Spaced%20repetition#literature-review to be of assistance.

Answer (score 6):

A [quick Pubmed search](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22spaced%20repetition%22) shows a couple of potential useful papers. The more promising:

- Karpicke, JD., & Bauernschmidt, A. (2011) [Spaced retrieval: absolute spacing enhances learning regardless of relative spacing](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21574747) *J Exp Psychol Learn Mem Cogn.* 37(5):1250-7
- Toppino, TC., Kasserman, JE., & Mracek WA. (1991) [The effect of spacing repetitions on the recognition memory of young children and adults](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2010724) *J Exp Child Psychol.* 51(1):123-38.

Comment: From the abstract of the first paper: >> However, there was no evidence that a particular relative spacing schedule (expanding, equal, or contracting) was inherently superior to another. Although expanding schedules afforded a pattern of increasing retrieval difficulty across repeated tests, this did not translate into gains in long-term retention. Repeated spaced retrieval had powerful effects on retention, but the relative schedule of repeated tests had no discernible impact.

Comment: +1 Could you please identify which part of the second paper (Toppino) is a comparizon of different spacing techniques (like Leitner, SM2, etc)? Thanks!